# An app that runs locally will not run on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, yarnpkg

I have an app that runs locally (with `yarn start` or `heroku local web`). When I did an initial import, it worked fine on Heroku, but after making a small change (and confirming that it worked locally), and then pushing it, the app would no longer start on Heroku.

After troubleshooting without success, I deleted the app in Heroku, then created a new app, and added the new remote to my app, and then pushed it. It suddenly worked, even though it was the exact same app!

As a test, I used the Express Generator to create a simple project, and the pushed it to Heroku

```
express --view pug --css sass --git .
yarn install
git init
git remote
heroku git:remote -a my-app-name
git commit -m "test"
git push heroku master
[app works fine]
yarn add bootstrap-sass
heroku local web
[app runs just fine locally]
git add .
git push heroku master
[no errors on console, but visiting the app results in a crash]
```

Once again, deleting the app on Heroku and pushing *the exact same app* to a new Heroku dyno works just fine.

Below is the log from Heroku. For the life of me, I can't figure out why this doesn't work.

```
2017-05-09T22:47:43.569610+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-05-09T22:47:43.569757+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs heroku-test
2017-05-09T22:47:43.569876+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-05-09T22:47:43.569995+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls heroku-test
2017-05-09T22:47:43.570120+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-05-09T22:47:43.574827+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-09T22:47:43.575046+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-05-09T22:47:43.575142+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-05-09T22:47:43.680034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-09T22:47:43.663434+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-09T22:47:44.907422+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cryptic-retreat-81313.herokuapp.com request_id=2377a688-77fa-4ce6-9fb5-f28a2cc57e2a fwd="74.77.147.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I want to figure out:

1. why this happens, and
2. how can I debug issues like this

**Edit**

I've created a [Github repo](https://github.com/dagoss/heroku-test) with a simple project that exhibits this problem.

Comment: I think we'll have to see your code.  Do you have any hardcoded paths or ports that might be different on heroku?

Comment: No. Like I said, I got the same results just using an unmodified project created using the [Express Generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html).

Comment: Are you using the proper environment variable to get the port you are supposed to start your server on.  The default Express generator app won't have that and you need it for running on Heroku.  As I said before, if we can see your code, we are more likely to be able to help.

Comment: @jfriend00 the default Express Generator app pulls in the port for an environment variable in `bin/www`, so I don't think that's it. That also wouldn't explain why the app works on first push to Heroku, but not the second.